# How can I normalize truncated variables for a neural network?

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, forecasting, normalization

Generally, I normalize variables using standard normal variates or `(x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin)`

[image]

But this only works well for variables that are not truncated, for example temperature that can take any positive or negative value. But doesn't do as well for truncated variables, say precipitation, which doesn't go below zero.

In that case, what kind of normalization techniques are to be used?